# Run and managment python script

Tags: python

I have web application on `Flask` and user can send some request which my script is processing and then, running another script in python in the console with some parameters like this:

```
import sys
os.system('python start.py -u 100 -p 122224')
```

All works good, but now I want controlling all running copies of my script like start, stop and pause.

How i can do this without crutches?

Comment: Have you tried multiprocessing module? http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: You should try subprocess: http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) and [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) modules. The first one allows you to execute external application. To use the second one, you'll be required to call some python code, but the management capabilities should be much wider.